# Can someone tell me why this script return NULL instead of give me result?

Tags: php, html

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "test");

function check_login($mail,$pwd){   
    global  $mysqli;    
    if($stmt=  $mysqli->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE mail = ? AND pwd = MD5(?)')){
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $mail, $pwd);       
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($count);
        $stmt->close();
        var_dump($count);
    }
    return ($count > 0 ? true : false);
}

check_login('test@gmail.com','pass');
```

I have write this script by seeing some script on stackoverflow.I tried to run it and found that $count is NULL after script execute.

I want to know why this is not worked for me. I have tried to run same command on Mysql and it's show me result.

someone help me on it..

Comment: I can see something like "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php - you also need to issue a fetch() call before the variable will be populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysqli::bind_result`](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_bind_result) needs to be invoked after the `->execute` and before the `->fetch` call. The fetch() isn't optional, as the (bound result) variable reference is merely an alternative to extracting the result row manually.

So in your code:

```
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($count);
    $stmt->fetch();  // result array thrown away
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't just copy and paste codes, especially ones that require messing with the database; understand what the code is trying to achieve, then, write yours. 
Second, replace

```
 
  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE mail = ? AND pwd = MD5(?)'
```

with

```
 
 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE mail =? AND pwd =?'
```

There's a chance the code didn't run because your passwords were stored in a plaintext on the database. 
Let us know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, no, I have run test script for learn and use MD5 for hash the password. it's working already.